# folium custom map tiles

Tags: leaflet, folium, stamen-maps

I want to add this map tile layer to my map – [Stamen toner-background](http://maps.stamen.com/toner-background/#6/55.702/15.853).
As I read in documentation I need to simply give custom url in the tiles attribute of map

```
mapa = folium.Map(width=1000, height=700, zoom_start=5.5,
              location=[52.5, 19], tiles='http://maps.stamen.com/toner-background/embed#6/{x}/{z}', attr="toner-bcg")
```

It loads but nothing is displayed.

I don't really know how this attribution thing works like and what should I do. I like the tile because it's like stamen toner but without country names and that makes my map a lot more beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

This is your lucky day, Stamen designs are built-in in Folium. You should run the following code:

```
mapa = folium.Map(width=1000, height=700, zoom_start=5.5,
              location=[52.5, 19], tiles='Stamen Toner')
```

This should solve the issue.

The reason your code was not working is because you were not using the correct URL templates. The format is one specified [here](http://maps.stamen.com/#toner/12/37.7706/-122.3782):

> http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
>   http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg
>   http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg

The code would look like this:

```
mapa = folium.Map(width=1000, height=700, zoom_start=5.5,
              location=[52.5, 19], tiles='http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png ')
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve Fernando's answer, the below code works for me:

```
mapa = folium.Map(width=1000, height=700, zoom_start=5.5,
    location=[52.5, 19], 
    tiles='http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png ', 
    attr="toner-bcg") # <-- note this
```

Comment: If you have an improvement to a previous answer, please edit or comment the answer instead of posing a new one.